# What's the best way to return an array inside of function of an ajax callback function?

Tags: jquery

I'm having problems getting the returned array from a return ajax callback function which is inside of another function. The problem being no array data is being received during the first cycle.....

```
              var testFile = $("#selection").val();
              var testData = getTestData(testFile); 
              alert(testData); // not working during the first time I run the function, empty


              function getTestData(testF)
              {
                  var testArray = [];

                  $.getJSON("test.php",{fileTest: testF}, function(data)
                  {
                         $.each(data, function(index, value)
                         {
                              if(value == "")
                              {
                              }else
                              {
                                 testArray[index] = value;
                              }
                         }
                   });
                   alert(testArray); // working I see the values
                   return testArray; // not working the first time running this function
              }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax calls are asynchronous.  What does that mean?

When you call `$.getJson` just *starts the HTTP request*, it does not immediately fill in `testArray`.  Instead, it fills in `testArray` *at some unspecified point in the future* after the HTTP request has completed.

The reason you see one of the alerts but not the other is simple:  By the time you click on the 'OK' button for the first alert, the request has finished and your answer is ready.  I'm willing to bet that the **first** alert that you're seeing (that fails) is actually the one inside `getTestData`.  Here's the likely sequence of events:

1. You call `getTestData()`
2. You start an HTTP request with `$.getJSON()`
3. the `alert(testArray)` *inside getTestData* is called, displaying an alert.  Since `testArray` hasn't been filled in yet, you have an empty array.
4. While you're sitting there looking at the alert, the `$.getJSON()` call completes and fills out `testArray`.
5. You click OK on the alert box.
6. `return testArray;` is run, returning the filled-in values
7. Your `alert` on line 3 is run, showing the array

Comment: but the alert test (with the return) always display the contents of the array even the first time so I don't understanding your point.

Comment: Updated with an explanation of what you are seeing.

Comment: Whatever you want to do with `testArray`, you have to from inside your callback.